# Optimizing WCF NetNamedPipeBinding performance

Tags: performance, wcf, wcf-binding, netnamedpipebinding

I have a WCF named pipe service that receives a byte array and writes it into an SQLite DB.
When I moved the SQLite insert logic into the WCF service the write performance decreased almost by half.
I went through various recommendation online but nothing seems to help.
My current configuration looks like this:

```
 pipeBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 5000000;
 pipeBinding.MaxBufferSize = 5000000;
 pipeBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 5000000;
 pipeBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 5000000;
 pipeBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None;
```

More tweaking recommendations would be more than welcome.

Comment: Is your service `PerSession`? `PerCall`?  Do you make repeated calls to the service using the same client proxy? Do you initiate a DB connection at the start of the service method?  If so, consider making your service `PerSession` and move the DB connection init to your service constructor where it can be used across calls for a given proxy

Comment: It has a non default constructor so it can't be PerSession.
I have configured
    behaviour.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;
It did help creating a single db instance.
I'm also looking at writing my own serialization.
Maybe skipping the base64 phase will help

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Using protobuf helped increasing the speed however most consuming action was a sum action on the SQLite table so I had change the structure of my db.